# Ormlite SQLiteCursor: close cursor on null twice or more

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I have class `Coach` which has Collection of `ScheduleEntity` objects;

```
public class Coach{

    @ForeignCollectionField(columnName = FIELD_SCHEDULE_ENTITY)
    private Collection<ScheduleEntity> scheduleEntities;
}
```

[...]

```
public class ScheduleEntity {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_COACH, foreign = true)
    private Coach coach;
}
```

I want to retrieve first `ScheduleEntity` for coach.

When I do it using `QueryBuilder`:

```
public ScheduleEntity getFirstScheduleForCoach(Coach coach) throws SQLException {
    QueryBuilder<ScheduleEntity, Long> queryBuilder = scheduleEntityDao.queryBuilder();
    queryBuilder
            .where()
            .eq(ScheduleEntity.FIELD_COACH, coach);
   return scheduleEntityDao.queryForFirst(queryBuilder.prepare());
```

**Some weird info appears in logcat:**

```
Close cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@42321aa0 on null twice or more
```

However when I do it in another way:

```
return scheduleEntityDao.queryForEq(ScheduleEntity.FIELD_COACH, coach).iterator().next();
```

Everything is fine (don't care about possible nullpointer).

What does that information mean? Am I doing something wrong or is it just normal behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, but I have never used ORMLite.

Comment: did you ever find the cause for this, or at least how to turn this off?

Comment: @NadavFima No, it's just warning and everything else works. I'm ignoring it

Comment: Yea, it works fine. just a shame to have this in the logcat for an app in the play store.

Comment: @Than check out the answer I posted. :)

makes it so much easier to look at the logcat now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead downloaded ORMLite's code.

in the `AndroidCompiledStatement` class on row 89, i changed the `close` method as follows:

before

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            cursor.close();
        } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
            throw new IOException("Problems closing Android cursor", e);
        }
    }
    cancellationHook = null;
}
```

after

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        try {
            cursor.close();
        } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
            throw new IOException("Problems closing Android cursor", e);
        }
    }
    cancellationHook = null;
}
```

simply checking that if the cursor is already closed pretty much fixed this for me, though you'd have to clone the ormlite-android git into your project.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll try that

Comment: For the record, this was fixed in the 5.0 version of ormlite.